# How to use Key tools to sign android apps in release modes on windows platform

Tags: android

I want to sign my android applications. I followed android developers website. but i didn't get full idea. I don't know how to get "Key tools" for windows. 
Please help how to get key tools and help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your don't need to use them directly
if you're using Android Studio go to build tab then go to generate signed APK and follow the wizard and create new key.

In Eclipse there is a similiar approach right click on your project then select Export project and follow the wizard.

Keep the created key in secure place because if you lose it you won't be able to update your application.

Comment: i used eclipse export option and a key generated in a file.i opened that file with notepad. it's was not readable. but how to use this key to get access to goolge maps and other google services.

Comment: You do NOT use this key anywhere else.Just for uploading your application to Google play.

Answer (score 0):

`keytool.exe` is in your JDK directory. For example: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\keytool.exe

Navigate to directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin **in your terminal** and then lauch

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

You can also add `;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\;` to your classpath in Windows and after adding keytool will be available in any place in terminal.